# How can I (semi-automatically) convert PNG to SVG?

Tags: graphics, svg, inkscape

I have a PNG image (or any other bitmap format, for that matter) I would like to convert into SVG.
Is there a way to help me do that? For example, some InkScape plug-in that automatically identify shapes and creates vector objects from them (instead of me doing it manually)?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/chiggum/mindthegap with noisy switch (-z) if the input image has blended colors and change the number of desired colors in output using (-n <num>).

Answer (score 1):

inkscape has [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) build in to it.

See http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html and http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Potrace